# Testing @RemoteAction method with mock data inserted in factory

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, code-coverage, remote-action

I'm struggling a little bit with accessing data which has been inserted through factory method in my RemoteAction method. Here is a code of RemoteAction method :

```
   @RemoteAction
   global static String eventdata(Id selectedDentist){
    calEvent[] visits = new calEvent[]{};
        for(Visit__c visit: [SELECT Id, StartDateTime__c, EndDateTime__c, Description__c, Accepted__c
                         FROM Visit__c
                         WHERE Owner.Id =: selectedDentist]) {
        DateTime startDT = visit.StartDateTime__c;
        DateTime endDT = visit.EndDateTime__c;

        calEvent myEvent = new calEvent();
        myEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
        myEvent.endString = endDT.format(dtFormat);
        myEvent.description = visit.Description__c;
        myEvent.editable = checkIfEditable(visit);
        myEvent.backgroundColor = checkWhatcolour(visit);                     
        visits.add(myEvent);
    }

    String jsonEvents = JSON.serialize(visits);
    jsonEvents = jsonEvents.replace('startString','start');
    jsonEvents = jsonEvents.replace('endString','end');
    jsonEvents = jsonEvents.replace('description', 'title');
    System.debug(jsonEvents);
    return jsonEvents;
}
```

What it does is adding to array of custom objects defined as follows, the objects which occur in my org and which ownerId is equal to one passed as argument:

```
// Class to hold calendar event data
public class calEvent {
    public String startString {get;set;}
    public String endString {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    public String backgroundColor {get;set;}
    public Boolean editable {get;set;}
}
```

I've written test which looks like these :

```
@isTest
public static void testRemoteVisitsDontExist() {
    User kiepskiDentist = [SELECT Id, LastName FROM User WHERE LastName = 'Kiepski' LIMIT 1];
    Test.startTest();
    TestDataFactory.createVisitsForDentist(kiepskiDentist.Id, 5);
    String returnedJson = CalendarController.eventdata(kiepskiDentist.Id);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

where factory method is defined:

```
@isTest
public class TestDataFactory {

public static void createVisitsForDentist(Id mockDentist, Integer amount) {
    List<Visit__c> visits = new List<Visit__c>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        Visit__c visit = new Visit__c();
        visit.OwnerId = mockDentist;
        visit.StartDateTime__c = Datetime.now().addHours(i);
        visit.EndDateTime__c = DateTime.now().addHours(i + 1);
        visit.Description__c = String.valueOf(i);
        visits.add(visit);
    }

    insert visits;
}
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Once I start test of my remote action, it doesn't execute code within `for` loop, so I assume there is no such element which would meet the requirements in my SOQL query, but once I debug it outside RemoteAction (still in test method) there are actually five objects inserted with all fields properly set.

**QUESTION**

Why does my test code not enter the `for` loop?

Comment: Any triggers/flows on Visit__c to change Owner on Insert?

Comment: Nope, before creating visit I already know the ID of the User who will be the owner so I'm just putting it as it is shown above. Neither trigger nor flow has been defined for that in the whole app, I guess it's not the case here.

Comment: Try changing `Owner.Id` to `OwnerId`.

Comment: Also note: *Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is **the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as **[smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests**.* -
 [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Comment: Is your Visit__c object private? Is your class defining eventdata method declared as "with sharing"?

Comment: so are you saying that if you remove the `@remoteAction` annotation the testmethod passes?